# What's the (base64Encoded:"aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ") this String meaning?

Tags: ios, swift

```
let data = Data(base64Encoded:"aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=" ,options:.ignoreUnknownCharacters)
```

what is the **"aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ"** meaning???

---

Language:`Swift 3`

Comment: Did you look up the `Data(base64Encoded:)` method in the documentation? – You can even Google for "aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=" ...

Answer (score 0):

`aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=` means `hello world` which encoded by base64.

You can check it your self on [this site](https://www.base64decode.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Base64 encoding is a way to encode something (this could be `hello world`, or an `image`, or anything) to a string value. You can then decode it to get the original data, so `aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=` becomes `hello word`.

An image would turn into a string and decode back to an image (bits / bytes).

The swift example you are giving is decoding the base64 encoded string to a `Data` object.